# Tizen Xamarin Wearable CircleProgressBarSurfaceItem in CarouselPage

Tags: xamarin, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy

I got a [CarouselPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/carousel-page) that contains three [ContentPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.contentpage?view=xamarin-forms) items. In the layout of the the second of the three ContentPages is [CircleProgressBarSurfaceItem](https://samsung.github.io/Tizen.CircularUI/guide/CirclePage.html#add-circleprogressbarsurfaceitem-in-circlepage) contained in the following way, just like in the [Galaxy Watch .NET get started tutorial](https://developer.samsung.com/tizen/Galaxy-Watch/get-started/using-circular-ui.html):

```
<ContentPage 
        ...>
        <AbsoluteLayout>
        <Label
              AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25"
              AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
              Text="0 Steps"
              FontSize="Large"
              HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
              VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>

        <w:CircleSurfaceView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <w:CircleSurfaceView.CircleSurfaceItems>
                <w:CircleProgressBarSurfaceItem
                  x:Name="ProgressBar"
                  BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                  BackgroundLineWidth="10"
                  BackgroundRadius="175"
                  BarColor="Blue"
                  BarLineWidth="10"
                  BarRadius="175"
                  IsVisible="True"
                  Value="0.5" />    
            </w:CircleSurfaceView.CircleSurfaceItems>
        </w:CircleSurfaceView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The result is just a blank black screen. The expected outcome is a border around the watch face that looks more or less like this image:

[image: CircleProgressBarSurfaceItem Example]

Isn't it possible to us the CircleProgressBarSurfaceItem in a CarouselPage parent container? I don't know what I am doing wrong, maybe one of you readers has an idea?

Comment: this used to be working indeed. they messed up in one of the latest update. I am not sure if it is caused by update XF 5 or Tizen CircularUI  nugets. if you downgrade to the older versions, you can see that it works just fine as you write.

Answer (score 1):

It is working well for me
Could you share your environment?
Which CircularUI version was used? run on device or emulator?

I can help you if you share your code

If you need more details feedback please leave comment on [here](https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.CircularUI/issues)

[image]

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with the W-6.0-circle-x86 emulator. Works fine when inside ContentPage and stops working when inside CarouselPage

Comment: I think that latest nuget updates messed up. I have an existing app used to work but after updating nugets, it stopped working. Not sure which one CircularUI or XF 5 update. I hadnt have time to test it. i have just seen not working and simply reverted back